# Internal Server Error when running Django with Scrapy

Tags: django, python-3.x, scrapy

I am making a relatively simple django app where you can add articles to it. Besides adding the article manually i am attempting to make use of `scrapy` and after you have added the title of the article manually you would visit the page of the article from the front-end and by the push of a button it would crawl another website to find that article and copy specific links it would find.

The problem is that i am facing several issues that results in `Internal Server Error`. The errors are `ValueError: signal only works in main thread` when I am not using the options `--noreload --nothreading` to run the django server. When running the server with the options mentioned just before, i get `raise error.ReactorNotRestartable() twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`.

I would not like to have to use the options `--noreload --nothreading` to run the django server in general as I read that it limits performance a lot.

I made a seperate app in my django project to keep things clean. The `views.py` I am using is the following

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from templates import *
from .models import *
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


def FetchLinks(request, pk, slug):
    mas = []
    fetched = []
    sites = []

    # this gets the sites where to search the article
    s = Sites.objects.all()
    for site in s:
        sites.append(site)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=pk)
        sites = SearchLinks(article.title)

        # this gets some expressions to find about the article
        sr = Srm.objects.all()
        for srm in sr:
            mas.append(srm)

        class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
            name = 'Spider'
            start_urls = sites

            def start_requests(self):
                urls = sites
                for url in urls:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

            def parse(self, response):
                for href in response.css("a::attr(href)").extract():
                    for ms in mas:
                        if ms in href:
                            fetched.append(href)

        subprocess = CrawlerProcess(settings={
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
            'FEED_URI': 'items.json',
            'LOG_LEVEL': 'WARNING',
        })

        process.crawl(MySpider)
        process.start()

        sobj, created = Links.objects.get_or_create(article=article)
        if created:
            sobj.set_urls(fetched)
        else:
            sobj.set_urls(fetched)

    linksobj.save()

        return reverse_lazy('detail', pk=pk, slug=slug)
    else:
        return render(request, 'content.html')
```

my `models.py`

```
class Sites(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Srm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Links(models.Model):
    urls = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    article = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article
```

and on the front end is just a button making a post request.

The following is from running `python3 manage.py runserver 8000 --noreload --nothreading`

```
Internal Server Error: /library/fetch/30/an-awesome-article/ 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/er/Desktop/projects/proj/projspider/views.py", line 59, in FetchLinks
    subprocess.start()
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 309, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1271, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1251, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 754, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
2019-07-27 10:14:48 [django.request] ERROR: Internal Server Error: /library/fetch/30/an-awesome-article/ 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/er/Desktop/projects/proj/projspider/views.py", line 59, in FetchLinks
    subprocess.start()
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 309, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1271, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1251, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 754, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
[27/Jul/2019 10:14:48] "POST /library/fetch/30/an-awesome-article/  HTTP/1.1" 500 89125
```

when I run `python3 manage.py runserver 8000`

```
Internal Server Error: /library/fetch/30/an-awesome-article/ 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/proj/projspider/views.py", line 55, in FetchLinks
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'WARNING',
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 268, in __init__
    install_shutdown_handlers(self._signal_shutdown)
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/ossignal.py", line 22, in install_shutdown_handlers
    reactor._handleSignals()
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 295, in _handleSignals
    _SignalReactorMixin._handleSignals(self)
  File "/home/er/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1232, in _handleSignals
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigInt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
[27/Jul/2019 09:23:04] "POST /library/fetch/30/an-awesome-article/  HTTP/1.1" 500 93336
```

Is there some standardized way to integrate scrapy with django that i should follow instead of the above?

I have seen some tutorials online like [this](https://blog.theodo.com/2019/01/data-scraping-scrapy-django-integration/) but there is nothing on how to trigger scrapy when a user requests so and like [this](https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/how-to-use-scrapy-with-django-application-c16fabd0e62e) where i do not understand how the scrapy project could read the models from Django so i can configure the spider based on information i extract from the models.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? How are you running the app?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated the question and added the stack trace along with the entire command to run the django server in the two cases.

Comment: The error `AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'` happens because you are returning a lazy reverse object and not a response, you need to change the return to something like this `return redirect('detail', pk=pk, slug=slug)`

Comment: Indeed now this error is gone and another one is in its place, i have updated the stacktrace accordingly.